# Calculated member in SSAS based on custom Last Year Date (Retail calendar)

Tags: ssas, mdx, calculated-columns

I have spent a lot of time solving this issue, but no success yet.

I have a Date dimension called [Dim Date] and in this table I have a [Date Key] which contains all the dates from '2013-07-01' to '2016-12-31'. I also have a measure called [Retail Revenue] which is a decimal number for that date. So far so easy!

We are a retail Calendar and all our calculations/comparisons are based on a retail calendar (which is a customized table in DW).

The date hierarchy in this calendar is as below (please see the screenshot):

-- retail year (e.g. 2017)

---- retail half year (e.g. 2017-H1)

------ retail quarter year (e.g. 2017-Q1)

-------- retail month (e.g. 201702) (months from 201701 to 201712)

---------- retail week (e.g. 201708) (weeks from 201701 to 201752)

------------ date key (e.g. 2016-08-22)

[**SCREENSHOT**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2wlX.jpg)

We also have an attribute called "Retail Last Year Date" which shows the equivalent date of last calendar date (e.g. 2015-08-24 in the screenshot).

I need to have a calculated member showing the "Retail Revenue" for last year (based on the attribute "Retail Last Year Date"), next to the regular "Retail Revenue" for [date key].

I tried to use ParallelPeriod and Scope, and could not get the numbers properly. Probably an easy task but I am not a hero in mdx unfortunately!

Will be more than thankful if anyone please can help me out with this.

Thanks
Rez

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps.

This is against `AdvWrks`. I've created a query scoped custom measure that gets the internet sales from the year before:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount LastYear] AS 
    (
      ParallelPeriod
      (
        [Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year]
       ,1
       ,[Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember
      )
     ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]
   ,[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount LastYear]
  } ON 0
 ,
    [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20070121]
  : 
    [Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[20070127] ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works];
```

Here are the results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response, but I didn't get how it uses the dimension property? because my calendar is customized and I cannot assume the last year calendar date is the same as this year. I have to read it from the dimension property "Retail Last Year Date").

Thanks